# Facebook Facepile can show total users connected?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-social-plugins

In the Facebook Facepile documentation, instructions read:

> To display users who have signed up for your site, specify your application id as the app_id parameter.

I found specifying the app id combined, along with NOT specifying a URL, will display the pictures of friends who have signed up (connected via Facebook) for the current URL. What I want is to display the total number of users who have connected, friend or not. Basically show me the pictures of my friends connected plus the total number of users.

Essentially this is the functionality of the Facepile when displaying the Likes, but I want to see connections, and not Likes.

Is this possible?